# Monitor cache ECC errors on STM32H7?

Tags: caching, stm32

I need to know whether ECC errors have been detected on the cache of a STM32H7. I know that ECC errors are always corrected on the cache, even multiple bits errors.

According to AN5372 of STMicro:

> As there is no failure notification or interface to ECC detection
> results of the CPU cache, the only solution to avoid the rare event of
> two-bit data cache ECC error is to manually periodically clean or even
> disable the cache. Flushing the cache periodically prevents the
> accumulation of more than one failing bit to single cache line.
> Disabling the cache may be extreme, but it is a valid preventive
> action when dealing with critical data.

I'm surprised that there is no way to know about ECC errors happening on the cache. In safety critical applications, it is a common practice to monitor ECC errors on memories, to log them for post-mortem analysis or to warn that an equipement should be replaced.